# Notepad++ regex extract two options

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've a list below:

```
7080508136242611718:7080508978035787525:7549dda86ba9af19:31050:install_id=7080508978035787525; store-country-code=us; store-idc=useast5; ttreq=1$fd2f36282a10633c5638a02cc54c19ff13f60755; passport_csrf_token=13bf74c4e5fe04307f0a99de9aed53f9; passport_csrf_token_default=13bf74c4e5fe04307f0a99de9aed53f9; odin_tt=11ed1b48fba2d7a9fe3d86929b3d52cebbad0ca7f7dbd127e220cfb3be279621ba04487517b536050a6ded9fbe50e300cd11615e2e9551523478e5484896a9dda800e55e428842872fcf862e8c57d439:1648559503:351451268482810:3f:49:8c:b7:8c:cb:c5379d41-6cf3-4152-9d48-7aa45f7f611c:79375640-197c-4aaa-86cf-4ef8e7238be2:1:AgICAw0AFockF-RPsNA-7qeIMtk5-CKdkW2eP4TZYMDY7A
7080507996291827206:7080508977079666438:6742591cc0d20580:31050:install_id=7080508977079666438; store-country-code=us; store-idc=useast5; ttreq=1$a119611bfe79541b0b4c029fe910b6507123eec2; passport_csrf_token=fb42bbd472462c17f45acb531deb057a; passport_csrf_token_default=fb42bbd472462c17f45acb531deb057a; odin_tt=6c3b06ff01fd67f42e3dccb60a1e69ca67cb8654f49662017acc209f7176517bcd13a374311f7a1b3538e6407fb237267abf43578d3180d8c834e7df886fa4377a9b950dbb6ff146e3fabf37158dcfa8:1648559508:351451233766930:dd:9e:82:59:5f:7f:596da881-89e8-4f60-b644-5fef23f0a422:f04adc87-56de-4191-a25f-843bec1d5818:1:AgICAw0AFockF-RPsNA-7qeIMtk5-CKdsYPWv4TZYMDY7A
7080509102451394054:7080509820378072837:e36dc9aceecfc1cc:31050:install_id=7080509820378072837; store-country-code=us; store-idc=useast5; ttreq=1$d94700921d5ee2b21992910a2a4e84dd0ade1ec8; passport_csrf_token=2d4f4eca772dbfcbb37548ff02da3166; passport_csrf_token_default=2d4f4eca772dbfcbb37548ff02da3166; odin_tt=53d6999ebe29c0d5144a9669331ce3307a290891370914dabadbfa0520114e6e76b9103c9a6db5476e139251ee478f3a305577a89e3fa07288b7aca00774d3fccbd03566687dbcfdce31700065295939:1648559700:351451299637010:71:de:41:2b:ad:b4:1eba1ae9-3216-40e1-be7f-00303e524c27:2713cbd3-7a4f-493e-b76f-ac6d56ab8045:5:AgMNAgIAhyQWF-RPsNA-7qeIMtk5-CKcsBcWP4TZYMDY7w
7080509086894851590:7080509909225604870:98be64e38551984d:31050:install_id=7080509909225604870; store-country-code=us; store-idc=useast5; ttreq=1$05929375d8605739d8ebdbb5ce15eb406da5c467; passport_csrf_token=c95c71ad206a1d371e5b67505ae25be8; passport_csrf_token_default=c95c71ad206a1d371e5b67505ae25be8; odin_tt=6ddaa02f6133e61a4c591ef2a872f0ec2339d8b6a3fc480575fe279b13ded615e1fa7de979e18565f3ac8b8229a19a98bdf79aa1804071dcc025e1a4cd5314522cf40a62ca961770baea1d5d653d6d64:1648559720:351451292934660:9d:cf:c3:92:f6:f5:787dfb42-f4bf-43fa-9c64-ded19a1b1660:366c3024-217d-4f85-90dd-d95a0fd3e296:4:AgICAw0AFockF-RPsNA-7qeIMtk5-CKcs7bUP4TZYMDY7w
7080509183397299718:7080509974838085382:f39db5d314071713:31050:install_id=7080509974838085382; store-country-code=us; store-idc=useast5; ttreq=1$561ee2083cb13f0849a9f09e7f89edfe08c7ce6c; passport_csrf_token=721a8fee6f4f97c16ed1923ad3bbc72d; passport_csrf_token_default=721a8fee6f4f97c16ed1923ad3bbc72d;
```

I'd like to extract first two options aka below:

```
7080508136242611718:7080508978035787525
7080507996291827206:7080508977079666438
7080509102451394054:7080509820378072837
7080509086894851590:7080509909225604870
7080509183397299718:7080509974838085382
```

I've tried: `*.:` but its remove the reset of text. and keeps only first.
I've tried `^.*[0-9]+.*$` to get the second one. but no success.

Hopefully somebody can help me with accurate regex.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern `*.:` by itself is not a valid regex, and this pattern `^.*[0-9]+.*$` matches the whole string with at least a single digit.

If you want to match the digits and `:` you could make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far and then match the rest of the line.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^\d+:\d+\K.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+:\d+` Match 1+ digits with `:` in between
- `\K.*` Clear the current match, and match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lKRwyO/1)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`^[^:]*:[^:]*\K.*`

When matching things with delimiters I will use a negated character set to match the contents.  In this case, the delimiter is a colon, so I want to match everything that isn't a colon until there's a colon.  Then I want to match everything that isn't a colon.  This will match everything up until the second colon.  Because I want to keep what I just matched, I am using `.*` after `\K`, which resets the match at that point and matches everything else.

That pattern can be replaced with nothing, and the result is the first two columns of each line left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Find: ^(\d+:\d+).*
Replace: $1
```

See [this regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/GRgAy0/1).

The `^(\d+:\d+).*` regex matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits + `:` + one or more digits (with `(\d+:\d+)`) at the beginning of a line (`^`) and then matches the rest of the line (with `.*`).

The `$1` replacement replaces the match with the Group 1 value.

See the demo and settings screenshot:

[image]

**As an alternative**, if there are chars other than digits you can also use

```
^([^:\v]+:[^:\v]+).*
```

where `[^:\v]+` matches one or more  chars other than a comma and any vertical whitespace.